# FooTableの利用について

Tags: jquery, css, html5

現在スマホ用の画面構築で、テーブルを可変にする為に
FooTableを利用しようとしています。
以下のサイトを参考にしてます。

http://www.webantena.net/javascriptjquery/plugin-footable/

ところが、肝心のソースが手に入りません。
というのも、ここに限らずどのサイトでも最終的にGithubから
ダウンロードするように誘導されますが、該当のソースが見つかりません。

なにより開閉ボタンの画像が一緒についてくると書いてありますが
そんなものは一切無いです。

もう対応してないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

公式の[ダウンロードページ](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html#download)の標準版（Standalone Version）から js と css をセットでダウンロードできます。

http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html#download

また、開閉ボタンは css を使って描かれているので、画像はなくても問題ないようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
Standaloneからダウンロードできました。
画像については、参考にしたサイトの方が間違ってますね・・・